# Blocking request with chrome manifest v3

Tags: chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I need to create extension that prevents script on the website from loading. How can i block web resource with Chome extension manifest v3?

Comment: Use [declarativeNetRequest](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/declarativeNetRequest/) (see the examples inside). If those scripts are loaded from a URL then add a blocking rule for resourceTypes `script`, otherwise for inline code you'll have to overwrite the value of Content-Security-Policy header, look for examples of forbidding inline scripts via CSP.

Comment: Thanks king / queen <3

Comment: How about adding your solution as an answer? @Worms207

Answer (score 0):

The official tutorial: [Replace blocking web request listeners](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/migrating/blocking-web-requests/#redirect-multiple-urls)

1. Edit your `blocking.json` save to your project path.

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "action": { "type": "block" },
    "condition": {
      "urlFilter": "<your blocking url>",
      "resourceTypes": ["<type>"]
    }
  }
]
```

2. Add `declarative_net_request` in `manifest.json`

```
"declarative_net_request": {
  "rule_resources": [
    {
      "id": "<your id>",
      "enabled": true,
      "path": "<project path>/blocking.json"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).